# I am trying to send mail using Python and outlook but getting error at end at mail.Send()

Tags: python, email, automation, outlook, win32com

```
OlaApp = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
olNS = olApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
mail  = ol.App.CreateItem(0)

mail.To = ''
mail.Subject = ''
mail.Body = ''
mail.Attachements.Add(max_file)
# here is max_file is latest file from the folder
mail.Display() -- able to see mail

mail.Send()
```

I am able to see the email but but sending the email getting below error:-

```
com_error :(-2147467260,'Operation aborted',None,None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have faced with a security issue in Outlook...

The `Send` method may fire an exception when you try to automate Outlook from an external application. It can also be a prompt issued by Outlook if you try to access any protected property or method. But in your case that is an exception. You get the security prompts/exceptions because Outlook is configured on the client computer in one of the following ways:

- Uses the default Outlook security settings (that is, no Group Policy set up)
- Uses security settings defined by Group Policy but does not have programmatic access policy applied
- Uses security settings defined by Group Policy which is set to warn when the antivirus software is inactive or out of date

You can create a group policy to prevent security prompts from displaying if any up-to-date antivirus software is installed on the system or just turn these warning off (which is not really recommended).

Read more about that in the [Security Behavior of the Outlook Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/How-to/Security/security-behavior-of-the-outlook-object-model) article.

Also you may consider using a low-level code on which Outlook is built and which doesn't give security issues - Extended MAPI. Consider using any third-party wrappers around that API such as [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption).

Another option would be the [Outlook Security Manager](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) which allows suppressing Outlook security issues at runtime on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Do not modelessly display the message (Display) and call Send while the message is still being displayed. It is one or another.